# Why does tf.image.ssim always return AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_shape'

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use `tf.image.ssim` to get the similarity between 2 images, however, it returns an attribute error. Since I am just directly using the TensorFlow code, I don't see any way to debug this issue.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
iris = datasets.load_iris()
x_train, y= tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(
    path='mnist.npz'
)

tf.image.ssim(
    x_train[0][0], x_train[0][0], 255
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MNIST returns a grayscale image which is in 2D, SSIM requires the image to be in 3D. So just expand the dims of the returned image that you want to compare and apply SSIM on it.

```
import numpy as np

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(
    path='mnist.npz'
)

x_train_expanded = np.expand_dims(x_train[0], axis=2)
print(tf.image.ssim(x_train_expanded, x_train_expanded, 255))
```

It returns the following:

```
tf.Tensor(1.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

The returned tensor contains an MS-SSIM value for each image in batch. The values are in the range [0, 1] and the example returns a value of 1 indicating both images are identical.

Comment: When you print `print(x_train[0].shape)` what do you get?

Comment: (60000, 28, 28)

Comment: Thank you, but it still does not run. I tried your answer verbatim on 2 different computers. The only change I made in the beginning was I added import tensorflow as tf.

Comment: Hi I updated the answer again. It has to do with MNIST data being greyscale.

Comment: If it does answer the question please do accept my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I get the following error now - AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_shape'

Comment: Maybe you have imported a library which I don't have? That's why it is running on your computer but not on mine.

Comment: I knew I had to import numpy :)
My tf version is 2.2.0

Comment: It should work and I updated the answer with the output.

Comment: Can you please tell me your tensorflow version?

Comment: 2.3.0 it should still work either way. You did import the dataset and set the return values just like I did as well right and print the value?

Comment: Yupp, I did that :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225854/discussion-between-yudhiesh-and-desert-ranger).